# Read/Write files on hdfs using Python

Tags: python, hdfs

I am a newbie to Python, I want to read a file from hdfs (which I have achieved).

after reading the file I am doing some string operations and I want to write these modified contents into the output file.

Reading the file I achieved using subprocess (which took a lot of time) since open didn't work for me.

```
cat = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", "/user/hdfs/test-python/input/test_replace"],stdout=PIPE)
```

Now, how to write to the output file with the modified contents is the question.

Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library for reading and writing to HDFS, like https://github.com/mtth/hdfs